# Is there any p4 (perforce) command to list out all the updated shelved change lists (CL)?

Tags: python, perforce

I need to see all the shelved CLs and updated shelved CLs in a specific perforce path.

My perforce path is //mainDir/subDir/endDir/

I can crack all the shelved CLs after a specific base CL with this command:

```
p4 changes "//mainDir/subDir/endDir/...@>[BASE_CL]" -s shelved
```

Similarly, I want to list out all the updated CLs which affected the same path.

Is there any command or p4Python function to do so?

- updated CL: suppose I shelve file1.txt in CL#100 on 2020-11-10. Then on 2020-11-11 I updated file1.txt and reshelve it on the same CL#100. I need to list out CL#100 on 2020-11-10 as well as 2020-11-11.

Comment: What exactly is an "updated shelved CL"?  Shelves are volatile, so there isn't really any difference between a changelist that you've just shelved and one that you've reshelved a few times.

Comment: Re-stating what @Samwise said: When you re-shelve it, it just updates the shelf. There is no "previous version" of that shelf, there's only the shelf. To get what you want, if you really want it, either create multiple shelves (rather than overwriting the same shelf), or use a branch.

Answer (score 0):

Found it
p4.run('changes', '//perforce/path' + '...@>' + str(1067180))